# Which kind of out did Contreras get at bottom 2nd in the game of Dodgers vs. Cubs at April 25, 2019?

Tags: baseball

at bottom 2nd in the [game](https://youtu.be/o_ln552Q6NM?t=2314) of Dodgers vs. Cubs at April 25, 2019, Contreras ran towards the home plate first and then back towards the 3rd base, and then out.

Why was that? Which kind of out did Contreras get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a tag out, per [5.09(b)(4)](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf).

[image: tagged out]